# Authenticate users with IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using identityserver4 A to authenticate clients and users of website B and everything works well but now I need to allow those users to request their secret keys stored in Website B from another website C by clicking a button from the website C that opens a new window that redirects users to the identityserver4 and authenticates them then this page closed and the response gets back to the caller website C, what is the best practice to do this?
In brief, I want to make my website B and IdentityServer4 act like Google when websites use it as an external identity provider

Answer (score 0):

From this requirement, it conforms to the authentication process of identityserver. If have no token, the client will be redirected to identityserver to authenticate and get the token, then the client will take the token to access the authorized resource.

Considering open a new window, a better method is to create a modal in the current page. In the modal, you can add iframe to navigate to the authentication page. When authenticating successfully, you can close the modal.
About when to pop up the modal, usually, when the client has been authenticated, it will have the cookie and carry them when sending request.

[image]

Comment: a modal will not make the user believes he is redirected to the identityserver, you cannot put your google credentials on a page without seeing the google domain in the address bar

Comment: If you can' t use modal, a new window is not a bad way. Because that is way for spa.